# How to convert curl "--user" command to Restsharp?

Tags: c#

My curl is

```
curl -X POST -d "email=jeff@example.com" -d "password=*******" 
         --user admin@example.com:password https://example.com/admin/web/users/add
```

what I have so far is

```
var client = new RestClient("https://example/admin/web/users/add");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "email=jeff@example.com" + "password=********", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

what i dont understand is where do I put

```
--user admin@example.com:password
```

Comment: I guess it uses HTTP Basic authentication, which is provided by RestSharp through `RestSharp.Authenticators.HttpBasicAuthenticator` (RestSharp has a few other authenticators, in case HTTP Basic auth is not suitable) . See the RestSharp documentation for how to utilize authenticators: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Authenticators

Comment: FYI curl default authentication is basic https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-u

Comment: @elgonzo
that worked
I had to use string auth = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("admin@example.com:password"));
and added 
 request.AddHeader("authorization", "Basic " + auth);
that fixed it

Comment: @MrMattMan, are you saying that HttpBasicAuthenticator didn't work; or did you simply not try HttpBasicAuthenticator? (I saw your comment edit only after writing my answer below)

Comment: everything is working now

thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 0):

Unless specified otherwise, curl uses HTTP Basic authentication when making HTTP(S) requests.

In RestSharp, HTTP Basic auth is provided via the `RestSharp.Authenticators.HttpBasicAuthenticator` type:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://example/admin/web/users/add");
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("admin@example.com", "password");
...
```